# Running a provisional script in one of the Homestead projects?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

In my Homestead directory, I have mapped two projects, one laravel, and one PHP. 
My PHP project could be run with `vagrant up`. This would then create tables in a database and everything setup to work. 
My question is how would I set up this to happen automatically after I `vagrant up` my Homestead machine?
I think that `vagrant up` inside a Homestead machine is not the best solution.

I know it is complicated if someone has any idea how this would be done, I am grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after.sh` to do anything you want to the Homestead VM after it's been booted but before it finishes the `vagrant up` process.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my problem lies elsewhere. Inside my php project there is vagrant file with its own after.sh file already that builds my project and fills database with tables and does all the necessary work. How would I fill my Homestead database dedicated for that project using after.sh file of my php project? Would that be even possible?

Comment: You don't want to run Vagrant inside another Vagrant machine. You could add something like `bash /path/to/other/after.sh` in your `after.sh`

Comment: It sounds like you have per-project and global Homestead running at the same time. Recommendation: only run global Homestead. If you need to have some per-project instances, make sure they are not included in the `folders` directive in your global Homestead.yaml file.

Comment: @joepferguson your second solution was right, I just had to specify the path  to the shell script and it worked, thank you!